# Using docutils.core.publish_string instead of publish_cmdline, `settings_overrides` argument carrying HTML-Specific Options takes no effect!

Tags: python, html, restructuredtext, docutils

Below is my code

```
from docutils.core import publish_string
from docutils.writers.html4css1 import Writer as HisWriter

args = {
    'stylesheet' : '/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css',
    'stylesheet-path' : None,
}

src = 'ccav'
print publish_string(src, writer=HisWriter(), settings_overrides=args)
```

I got the following error:

```
AssertionError: stylesheet and stylesheet_path are mutually exclusive.
```

So, I change `args` to:

```
args = {
    'stylesheet-path' : '/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css',
    'stylesheet' : None,
}
```

Now, There is no errors. But, The stylesheet inserted into the HTML output is not the content of `/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css`. It is still `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/writers/html4css1/html4css1.css`.

That is to say, unlike specify options in command line when using publish_cmdline, the `settings_overrides` argument carrying HTML-Specific Options takes no effect when using publish_string.

Comment: What happens when you set `'stylesheet' : '/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css'` and also set `'stylesheet-path' : './' or something like that at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion！ I have tried。let `args={'stylesheet-path' : '/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css','stylesheet' : './',}` or `args={'stylesheet' : '/home/wonder/lab/css/note.css','stylesheet-path' : './',}`。 But in the two situations, I always get the same as before: `AssertionError: stylesheet and stylesheet_path are mutually exclusive.`

Comment: I have found a example use of publish_string [click to visit](http://www.google.com/codesearch#5nXISCkkwPs/transforms/rest.py&q=publish_string&type=cs). but it use no HTML-Spec options at all.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it works for me. Also remember to accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from docutils.core import publish_string
from docutils.writers.html4css1 import Writer as HisWriter

src = 'ccav'
args = {
    'stylesheet_path' : '/path/to/your/stylesheet'

}
print publish_string(src, writer=HisWriter(), settings=None, settings_overrides=args)
```

You need to do `settings = None` and use `stylesheet_path` rather than `stylesheet` to get it to ignore the built in stylesheet.

Edit: Note that I found this answer in the source of one of the example scripts that comes with distutils, so even though `settings = None` seems bad, it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code have solved my problem. It works as I expects. But even you have miss the point! `settings=None` is unnecessary. Don't You see the Symbol `stylesheet_path` in the code you pasted, It's `stylesheet_path` rather than `stylesheet-path`!

Comment: HA! Wow, I didn't notice that at all. Copy-Paste to the rescue!

Comment: I have to complain that what a bad design it is, How can it use `stylesheet-path` in settings_spec and cmd line but use a different `stylesheet_path` in this situation! it has wasted me a great deal of time! And I can find nothing about it in the [documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/runtime-settings.html)

Comment: It's really about the worst documentation I've ever seen. Just reading the source is much easier.

Comment: Thank you! could you please give me the link to the source code you refer to?

Comment: I looked at several files but I think http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/docutils/trunk/docutils/docutils/writers/html4css1/__init__.py?revision=7061&content-type=text%2Fplain was the one that I copied from.

Comment: Maybe also http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/docutils/trunk/docutils/docutils/examples.py?view=markup

Comment: Got it! Many thanks! `stackoverflow` is a wonderful place. I am Chinese. In China, few people use python, seldom people use rst. When I encounter difficulties，it is difficult to find a solution when `Google` cannot help. recently, I found that google often takes me to `stackoverflow`. So I join here. Sorry for my poor English, I have to talk with the assistant of Google translator.